# count number of Groups Integer

Tags: vba, excel-formula

does any know how to group numbers and count number of groups?
for example image below are the lengths of cut bars and I need to know how many 20ft bar should I get. Hence, sum of all bars divided by 20 does not work. Thank you

[image]

Comment: If you are searching for specific numbers (lengths) you can use `COUNTIF` with one cell containing the length you are looking for

Comment: The optimal solution is not a question of simple math - see for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem

Comment: @TimWilliams thank you tim, I'll try to study this later. do you know how to translate the formula to excel? thanks

Comment: I've never tried to write something like this but maybe check this page:  http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/09/12/cutting-stock-lengths/

Comment: @James The question should probably be edited for clarity. The problem in question is that when using real life materials, you cannot simply sum the needed quantities and buy that number but rather you must buy the amount that would allow you to create the needed quantities. For example, if you need 10x 18 ft pieces, you still have to buy 10 x 20 ft stock and not 9x 20 ft stock. The poster was asking if a formula exists to quickly determine this number or if VBA could be used to quickly find it.

Comment: It's clear enough to me - what is the minimum number of 20ft items which would be needed to produce the list of required lengths?   As noted in the comments it's not a new problem but an example of a known set of problems (ie. a type of "knapsack" optimization)

Comment: Hey @TimWilliams, I just check "dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/09/12/cutting-stock-lengths" and this is what i'm looking for. I just made a few tweaks to incorporate in my spreadsheet. you're the best.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SUMPRODUCT()` formula as follows:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ROUNDUP(A2:A50/20,0))
```

where `A2:A50` is the range where the data is.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to practice my UDFs and my Class-Modules so I took this question as an opportunity to challenge myself and created something that hopefully does what you need it to.

The UDF `CUTLENGTHS` will accept your list of required pieces, an input stock length and an *optional* blade width. It will then output a long text that details the number of needed stock and which cuts go into which stock piece.

Here's an example of the input and output:
[image: CUTLENGTHS]

This is the UDF which needs to go into a code module

```vb
Public Function CUTLENGTHS(ByRef RequiredLengths As Range, ByVal StockLength As Double, Optional BladeWidth As Double = 0) As String
    
    'Saving the Required Lengths into a 1D array
    Dim Required() As Variant, i As Long, val As Variant, rCount As Long
    ReDim Required(0 To RequiredLengths.Cells.Count - 1)
    For i = 1 To RequiredLengths.Cells.Count
        val = RequiredLengths.Cells(i).Value
        If Not IsEmpty(val) And IsNumeric(val) Then 'Skip blanks and text
            If val <= StockLength Then 'Only accept valid inputs
                Required(rCount) = CDbl(val)
                rCount = rCount + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve Required(0 To rCount - 1)
    
    'Sort Largest to smallest
    If UBound(Required) > LBound(Required) Then
        Dim FinishedSorting As Boolean, tmpDbl As Double
        While Not FinishedSorting
            FinishedSorting = True
            For i = LBound(Required) To UBound(Required) - 1
                If Required(i) < Required(i + 1) Then
                    tmpDbl = Required(i + 1)
                    Required(i + 1) = Required(i)
                    Required(i) = tmpDbl
                    FinishedSorting = False
                End If
            Next i
        Wend
    End If
    
    'Assign each required length to a Stock, and calculate the number of stocks needed.
    Dim Stocks() As Stock, n As Long 'n is the number of Stocks
    While Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Required) > 0
        ReDim Preserve Stocks(n)
        Set Stocks(n) = New Stock
        Stocks(n).StockLength = StockLength
        Stocks(n).BladeWidth = BladeWidth
        For i = LBound(Required) To UBound(Required)
            If Required(i) > 0 And Stocks(n).RemainingLength >= (Required(i) - BladeWidth * (Stocks(n).RemainingLength <> StockLength)) Then
                Stocks(n).AddCut Required(i)
                Required(i) = 0 'once a piece is assigned to a Stock it is removed from the array
            End If
        Next i
        n = n + 1
    Wend
    
    Dim OutputText As String
    OutputText = "Total Stock: " & n & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    For i = LBound(Stocks) To UBound(Stocks)
        OutputText = OutputText & "Stock #" & i + 1 & vbNewLine & Stocks(i).GetText
        If i < UBound(Stocks) Then OutputText = OutputText & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    Next i
    
    CUTLENGTHS = OutputText
    
End Function
```

And this is the class-module `Stock`

```vb
Private MyCuts() As Double
Private StartingLength As Double
Private MyBladeWidth As Double
Private SumofCuts As Double
Private BladeWidthLosses As Double

Property Let StockLength(ByVal Length As Double)
    StartingLength = Length
End Property
Property Get StockLength() As Double
    StockLength = StartingLength
End Property
Property Let BladeWidth(ByVal width As Double)
    MyBladeWidth = width
End Property
Property Get BladeWidth() As Double
    BladeWidth = MyBladeWidth
End Property
Property Get Cuts() As Double()
    Cuts = MyCuts
End Property

Public Sub AddCut(ByVal CutLength As Double)
    If Initialized(MyCuts) Then
        ReDim Preserve MyCuts(UBound(MyCuts) + 1)
    Else
        ReDim MyCuts(0)
    End If
    MyCuts(UBound(MyCuts)) = CutLength
    SumofCuts = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MyCuts)
    BladeWidthLosses = MyBladeWidth * UBound(MyCuts)
End Sub

Public Function RemainingLength() As Double
    RemainingLength = StartingLength - SumofCuts - BladeWidthLosses
End Function

Public Function GetText() As String
    If Not Initialized(MyCuts) Then Exit Function
    
    Dim strOut As String, i As Long
    
    'Outputting the cut lengths like: "Lengths: 9, 7.5, 1.25"
    strOut = UBound(MyCuts) + 1 & " Length" & IIf(UBound(MyCuts) > LBound(MyCuts), "s", "") & ": "
    For i = LBound(MyCuts) To UBound(MyCuts)
        strOut = strOut & Format(MyCuts(i), "0" & IIf(MyCuts(i) <> CInt(MyCuts(i)), ".##;;0", ""))
        If i < UBound(MyCuts) Then strOut = strOut & IIf(UBound(MyCuts) = LBound(MyCuts) + 1, " & ", ", ")
    Next i
    
    'Showing the wasted stock like "Waste: 1.5" (The blade width losses are not counted as waste)
    strOut = strOut & vbNewLine & "Waste: " & Format(RemainingLength(), "0" & IIf(RemainingLength() <> CInt(RemainingLength()), ".##;;0", ""))
    
    GetText = strOut
End Function
Private Function Initialized(ByRef Arr As Variant) As Boolean
    'Determines if the given input is an initialized array
    Initialized = True
    On Error Resume Next
    If UBound(Arr) = -1 Then
        Initialized = False
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: Important note: Since BladeWidth is in ft. A 1/4 inch blade would be `=0.25/12` or `0.020833` and not `0.25` like I have put in the example.